# Multiply defined labels with \usebox

Tags: cross-referencing, boxes, warnings

I want to duplicate some content without re-defining its labels. For example,

```
\newbox{\foobox}
\sbox{\foobox}{\vbox{\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}}
\usebox{\foobox}
\usebox{\foobox}
```

will emit a warning, because `sec:foo` is defined more than once. Is there any way to prevent the second `\usebox` from writing to the aux file?

Comment: You basically can't, with this approach. When the `\vbox` is built, the `\label` command is translated into a whatsit that contains a `\write` instruction and it can't be disabled any more, because the vertical list is already packaged.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate. Is there any way to duplicate content without affecting what is to be typeset? My original intent was to typeset a bunch of labelled theorems multiple times. With a plain macro instead of a box, the theorem numbering counters (of course) were also incremented the second time, which I do not want.

Comment: There are two problems. (1) Avoid `\label` doing a `\write` in the later usages: this might be solved by absorbing the text as a macro replacement text; (2) “freezing” all counters to their current value. Could you be more specific about the problem and what counters you need to be frozen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, you want to have the first `\label` intact and to disable the others.
Then the following uses a trick:

1. The box is created with two commands `\BeginIgnoreAux{<id>}` and `\EndIgnoreAux` before and after the original contents.
   These macros write markers into the `.aux` file with the result, the
   label stuff gets in between.
2. If the `.aux` file is read, then the label stuff is executed as usual the first time. If `\BeginIgnoreAux{<id>}` is called more then once with the same `<id>`, then the label stuff is ignored. This avoids duplicate labels.
3. LaTeX reads the `.aux` file twice. At the end of the document the `.toc` files are written, for example. Therefore Macro `\AuxResetIgnoreStuff` clears the `<id>`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\global\let\AuxResetIgnoreStuff\@empty
\usepackage{auxhook}
\AddLineBeginAux{\string\AuxResetIgnoreStuff}

% Macros inside the `.aux' file
\newcommand*{\AuxBeginIgnore}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{ignore@#1}{%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname ignore@#1\endcsname\@empty
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\AuxResetIgnoreStuff
    \expandafter{%
      \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname ignore@#1\endcsname\relax
    }%
  }\AuxSkip
}
\def\AuxSkip#1\AuxEndIgnore{}
\let\AuxEndIgnore\relax

% User commands
\newcommand*{\BeginIgnoreAux}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\AuxBeginIgnore{#1}%
  }%
}   
\newcommand*{\EndIgnoreAux}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%  
    \string\AuxEndIgnore
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newbox{\foobox}
\sbox{\foobox}{%
  \BeginIgnoreAux{foo}%
  \vbox{\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}}%
  \EndIgnoreAux
}
\noindent
\usebox{\foobox}
\usebox{\foobox}

\noindent
Reference to the first label: \ref{sec:foo}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The `.aux` file contains:

```
\relax 
\AuxResetIgnoreStuff
\AuxBeginIgnore{foo}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Foo}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:foo}{{1}{1}}
\AuxEndIgnore
\AuxBeginIgnore{foo}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Foo}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:foo}{{1}{1}}
\AuxEndIgnore
```

And the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Foo}{1}
```